# node-sp-auth requires undefined Headers constructor

Tags: node.js, sharepoint

I tried to access our internal sharepoint with the node-sp-auth library for Node.js but got stuck with a mysetrious error:

> ReferenceError: Headers is not defined

I could trace it back to an internal function, that uses a constructor with that name.
Seems for me like there might be some dependencies missing?

In the following my code:

```
const pnp      = require("sp-pnp-js");

let w = new pnp.Web("https://acmint.myatos.net/PWA/KanbanBoard/");
pnp.sp.web.lists.get().catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
}).then(r => {

console.log(r);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PnP-JS-Core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core) utilizes [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to perform REST requests. 
To get rid of this error you need to bring support for `window.fetch` to Node.js, for example using [`node-fetch` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch).

The following example demonstrates how to utilize `node-fetch` with [PnP-JS-Core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core):

```
const pnp = require("sp-pnp-js");

global.fetch = require('node-fetch');
global.Headers = require('node-fetch').Headers;
global.Request = require('node-fetch').Request;


let w = new pnp.Web("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/");
pnp.sp.web.lists.get().catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
}).then(r => {
    console.log(r);
});
```

For browser scenario follow [#Polyfill section](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Install-and-Use) on how to include polyfills

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved it doing manual Htttp requests.